# How to start using google tests on a Yocto(Open Embedded) System

Tags: c++, linux, embedded-linux, yocto, googletest

I'm doing a project for ARM64 devices and am using Linux Embedded as the OS. I am trying to using Google Tests but when running bitbake, it is failing.
Heres the error:

```
| CMake Error at /#####/tmp-glibc/work/#####-oe-linux/project_name/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:40 (message):
|   Error running test executable.
|
|     Path: '/#####/tmp-glibc/work/#####-oe-linux/project_name/1.0-r0/build/projectName/hello_test'
|     Result: 126
|     Output:
|
|
|
|
| ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
| WARNING: /#####/tmp-glibc/work/#####-oe-linux/project_name/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.19988:1 exit 1 from 'eval ${DESTDIR:+DESTDIR=${DESTDIR} }VERBOSE=1 cmake --build '/#####/tmp-glibc/work/#####-oe-linux/project_name/1.0-r0/build' "$@" -- ${EXTRA_OECMAKE_BUILD}'
```

I've edited the cmake in my src folder and added these components wrt Gtests:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
# set the project name and version
project(project_name)

#specify C++ standards
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_compile_options (-std=c++11 -Wall)

configure_file(common/inc/common.h.in common.h)

add_definitions(-DPACKAGE_ARCH=${PACKAGE_ARCH})
add_definitions(-DPACKAGE_DISTRO=${PACKAGE_DISTRO})

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

add_subdirectory (executable_name ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/srclocation)
```

CMake for the file containing test case:

```
set(S_EXECUTABLE executableName)
#specify C++ standards
add_compile_options (-std=c++11 -Wall)

# add the executable
add_executable(${S_EXECUTABLE } src/abc.cpp)
target_include_directories(${S_EXECUTABLE}
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
    PUBLIC ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

install(
  TARGETS ${S_EXECUTABLE}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${FOOBAR_INSTALL_BINDIR}
  PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ
              GROUP_EXECUTE GROUP_READ
              GROUP_EXECUTE GROUP_READ
)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
  hello_test
  src/hello_test.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
  hello_test
  gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(hello_test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656529/how-to-start-using-google-tests-on-a-yoctoopen-embedded-system

This was a cross compiler issue as stated in the comments